# Once again confused about what is not an answer

Tags: discussion, support, flags, deleted-answers

I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22297759/css-white-space-nowrap-not-working-in-table-column/22299405#22299405) while reviewing in 10K+ queue, had 2 x not an answer flags on it and I was just about to flag it as *it has invalid flags* but then..

Up until now I would have said [it's an attempt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22297759/css-white-space-nowrap-not-working-in-table-column/22299405#22299405) to answer the question (poor-quality) but still an attempt. It's not spam, no hate speech, not a racist comment, none of these...

Personally, I wouldn't have deleted [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22297759/css-white-space-nowrap-not-working-in-table-column/22299405#22299405) but it actually did get deleted by a mod (*and not community*)

AFAIK, moderators don't delete answers based on the correctness of an answer but rather based on spam, link-only to another SO answer, etc.

So why was this one deleted?

Comment: Excellent question. It's a poor answer alright, but it should be downvoted rather than deleted....The other answer is arguably even worse and it's still there.

Comment: I can't see the specific post, but in general just because it isn't "Not An Answer" doesn't mean it shouldn't be deleted.  If it is a very low quality attempt to answer a question it isn't "Not an Answer" but probably still should be deleted.

Comment: You should also look at the edit history; the first draft was definitely a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This was my mistake. The first time I read the answer, I incorrectly interpreted it that way. I've undeleted the post, and removed the comment the post was converted into. Couldn't tell you how I managed to do that, it was clearly an attempt to answer the question. Sorry everyone!

Comment: The first draft wasn't though; the edited version *is*. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ahh, that was probably it!

Comment: You may want to clear that 'not an answer' comment underneath it, it's obsolete now.

Answer (score -3):

I tend to view all 'answers' that start with 'try' as 'not an answer'.

If the writer *knows* that a particular approach will work, they should say so. If the writer is just guessing, or suggesting a debugging strategy, I think they should be commenting.

Comment: I couldn't tell you how many of my own answers start with `try` this or that as depending on the problem the OP is facing there may not always be a definite answer. Sometimes your `try` guess is the solution then you can edit/update your answer. I also don't think this answers my question in the original post therefore I have expressed my disagreement with -1.

Comment: If there's no definite answer, there's no answer. There's just a comment. If the comment leads to evidence of an answer, then there's an answer. That's my view. Your vote is your vote.

Comment: Sometimes "try X" doesn't necessarily mean that author is unsure about the correctness of an answer. For novice questions a good answer is often a suggestion of direction OP should go (e.g. "try using a dictionary instead of a list, like this:") but many possible solutions exist.

Comment: I don't think I've used `try`, but it is not rare that I use `should`, because I don't have a crystal ball that allows me to know that the asker is **definitively not** operating in an environment that would make my answer ineffective.